# When is an image inside an iFrame loaded?

Tags: html, image, iframe

Assume I have a website containing an <img>-Tag displaying an image from an external source.
If my site gets embedded into another site with an <iFrame>, where is the image loading?
Is my site loading the image and sends it to the iFrame or is my site just sending plain HTML, CSS and JS and the image is pulled from the external source on the website embedding my site? Or is it just pulled from the client?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers request resources from the URLs they are given.

If you want to proxy the request through your own site then you have to provide a URL to your site and write server-side code that makes the proxy request.